# CentOS is not detecting my Microphone, I can't save alsamixer settings

Tags: centos, alsa, microphone, alsamixer

I can't record and I was reviewing my Microphone.

[image]

Checking

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ uname -r
5.7.8-1.el8.elrepo.x86_64
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$

[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

In other side:

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
options snd-hda-intel model=pch position_fix=1
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

now checking with `alsamixer`
I get this.

[image]

As you can see: I have in Card: `PulseAudio`

Changing with `F6`.

[image]

and selecting `F5` in order to view all Settings.

But, exiting the changes are not saved. And the Selected Sound Card is not preserved.

[image]

Now, I want to use `sudo alsamixer`.

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ sudo alsamixer
[sudo] password for joseluisbz: 
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

cannot open mixer: Connection refused
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

[image]

Later, after to do changes:

```
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ alsamixer
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ alsactl store
alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$

[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ alsactl init
alsactl: sysfs_init:48: sysfs path '/sys' is invalid

Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC257" "HDA:10ec0257,17aa3835,00100001 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000" "0x17aa" "0x3816"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$

[joseluisbz@centos ~]$ alsactl restore
alsactl: state_lock:125: file /var/lib/alsa/asound.state lock error: File exists
alsactl: load_state:1683: Cannot open /var/lib/alsa/asound.state for reading: File exists
alsactl: sysfs_init:48: sysfs path '/sys' is invalid

Found hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC257" "HDA:10ec0257,17aa3835,00100001 HDA:8086280b,80860101,00100000" "0x17aa" "0x3816"
Hardware is initialized using a generic method
[joseluisbz@centos ~]$
```

**How Can I solve this?**

**EDIT 1**:

When I run `pulseaudio -D` I get:

```
$ pulseaudio -D
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
$
```

with `pulseaudio -v`

```
$ pulseaudio -v
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to acquire high-priority scheduling: Permission denied
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 14.0-rebootstrapped
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is fb78af0a9247484aad9831a10a928084.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 3.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/joseluisbz/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib64/pulse-14.0/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
$
```

In order to kill it must be: `$ rm -rf /home/joseluisbz/.config/pulse`

With: `ps aux | grep pulseaudio`

```
$  ps aux | grep pulseaudio
joselui+    2471  0.0  0.0 1563156 12648 ?       Ssl  23:51   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
joselui+    4960  0.0  0.0 221928  1104 pts/0    S+   23:59   0:00 grep --color=auto pulseaudio
$
```

with `pulseaudio --dump-conf`

```
$ pulseaudio --dump-conf
### Read from configuration file: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ###
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
rescue-streams = yes
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib64/pulse-14.0/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = 
log-level = notice
resample-method = auto
avoid-resampling = no
enable-remixing = yes
remixing-use-all-sink-channels = yes
remixing-produce-lfe = no
remixing-consume-lfe = no
lfe-crossover-freq = 0
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 4
default-fragment-size-msec = 25
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 8000
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 200000
$
```

Restarting `pulseaudio`:

```
$ pulseaudio --kill
$ pulseaudio --start
$
```

Listing `dnf list installed | grep alsa`

```
$ dnf list installed | grep alsa
alsa-firmware.noarch                               1.0.29-6.el8                                  @AppStream                
alsa-lib.x86_64                                    1.2.4-5.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-lib-devel.x86_64                              1.2.4-5.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-plugins-arcamav.x86_64                        1.1.9-1.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-plugins-freeworld-a52.x86_64                  1.1.6-5.el8                                   @rpmfusion-free-updates   
alsa-plugins-freeworld-lavrate.x86_64              1.1.6-5.el8                                   @rpmfusion-free-updates   
alsa-plugins-maemo.x86_64                          1.1.9-1.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-plugins-oss.x86_64                            1.1.9-1.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-plugins-pulseaudio.x86_64                     1.1.9-1.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-plugins-samplerate.x86_64                     1.1.9-1.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-plugins-speex.x86_64                          1.1.9-1.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-plugins-upmix.x86_64                          1.1.9-1.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-plugins-usbstream.x86_64                      1.1.9-1.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-plugins-vdownmix.x86_64                       1.1.9-1.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-tools-firmware.x86_64                         1.1.6-1.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-ucm.noarch                                    1.2.4-5.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-utils.x86_64                                  1.2.4-2.el8                                   @AppStream                
alsa-utils-alsabat.x86_64                          1.2.4-2.el8                                   @AppStream                
$
```

Updating..

```
$ sudo dnf update alsa-lib alsa-utils
Last metadata expiration check: 1:37:40 ago on Thu 22 Dec 2022 10:50:20 PM -05.
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data: static_context [line 9 col 3]
Dependencies resolved.
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                               Architecture                                  Version                                                Repository                                        Size
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrading:
 alsa-lib                                              x86_64                                        1.2.7.2-1.el8                                          appstream                                        496 k
 alsa-lib-devel                                        x86_64                                        1.2.7.2-1.el8                                          appstream                                        1.0 M
 alsa-utils                                            x86_64                                        1.2.7-1.el8                                            appstream                                        1.1 M

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade  3 Packages

Total download size: 2.6 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
```